# radar chart with boxplot/ Violin plot

Tags: d3.js, charts, highcharts

I have a radar/spider chart.

The input to this chart can be in the format as shown:

```
[23, 34, 54, [4, 3, 67], 45, 5]
```

When there is a single value, it is shown as a data point, but when it is an array of points, I want the data to be shown in a boxplot instead (as in the image shown below).

My question is which javascript library is suitable for this type of requirement? I tried using 'Highcharts', but I could not get the boxplot.

[image]

Comment: I think this question is better suited for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jrook thanks for the input. i have posted a question on the above mentioned site

Answer (score 0):

I think d3js would be a good choice. You could create two separate charts with one overlaying the other.

Box chart 
https://beta.observablehq.com/@mbostock/d3-box-plot

Radar Spider chart
http://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/6506614